# How does a category work?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective-c and need to extend a standard class of a framework with an instance variable plus accessors. I heard that this is done with a so called "category", which sounds pretty confusing to me. How does this basically work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A category adds methods to the table of methods inside a class.  It's very handy for adding application specific methods to existing framework classes.

If you need to add instance variables to a class, a category won't do the job -- categories only add methods, not data.  To add instance variables, you must subclass.

Comment: You can add variables to a category with [Associated Objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/)

Answer (score 7):

A category of a class adds methods to that class. It cannot add instance variables.

If you need to add instance variables you may want to subclass instead.

Comment: If you need to add instance variables, you can use associated objects.