# How to understand NSObject, it is both protocol and interface

Tags: iphone, interface, protocols, nsobject

You can see following in NSObject.h file

// 1. here is a protocol

```
@protocol NSObject
```

// 2. here is an interface, conforming to the above protocol

```
@interface NSObject <NSObject> {
    ...
```

// 3. what is the meaning of "( )" below?  NSCoderMethods is a protocol

```
@interface NSObject (NSCoderMethods)
```

NSObject is so important that I need to understand, why is it designed like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.

It is a class (interface) because all concrete classes in ObjC nowadays inherit implementations from NSObject, to support features such as reference-counting and run-time type checking.

---

2.

Now for the protocol... it exists because NSObject is not the only root class that supports the `-retain` and `-performSelector:` etc methods.

One important class is [NSProxy](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProxy_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which acts as a proxy to forward messages to some actual objects.

The targets of NSProxy are usually NSObjects, so the interface should also support `-retain` and `-performSelector:` etc methods. But NSProxy cannot inherit from NSObject because there is no **is-a** relationship between the two.

To express the sibling relationship, both are made to adopt the same protocol, which, unfortunately, also called NSObject.

Making NSObject a protocol also has an advantage that, user-defined protocols can request adopters to support all usual NSObject operations by

```
@protocol Foo <NSObject>
...
```

---

3.

[It's a category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862299/how-does-a-category-work-in-objective-c), which adds extra method implementations to NSObject.

Comment: Thanks very much.
In Java, there is Object, very similar with NSObject. All java classes inherit from Object. In ObjectC, need explicitly inherit from NSObject.