# What is “category” in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, categories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does a category work in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862299/how-does-a-category-work-in-objective-c)

I am just getting started with Objective-C and was wondering when and where am i supposed to use category in objective C. is it a class or a protocol? An explanatory example would be of great help.
Thanks

Comment: Not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862299/ which is asking about the mechanics of how categories work, not what they are.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A category allows you to add methods to an existing class—even to one for which you do not have the source.

Categories are a powerful feature that allows you to extend the functionality of existing classes without subclassing

Check the apple doc for the [Category in Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html)

Comment: Categories in Objective-C are similar to [Ruby open classes](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_open_classes.html) and [C# extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: Just want to report that the Category in ObjC link no longer exists.

Comment: @Arc676 Categories definitely still exist.

Comment: Both links are expired now.

Comment: Official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the Objective-C 2.0 programming Language document about [Categories and Extensions.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1)

As you are just getting started it's a good doc to have on hand to look things up.

There is also a section on [Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Category.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH5-SW1) in the Cocoa Core Competencies document, which is easier to get started with, and also has a lot of useful information for the beginner.

Comment: That first link is now obsolete. Apple redirects to listing of documentation.