# Space at end of text not visible in right-aligned UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, text-alignment

I have a right-aligned `UITextField`.  Initially spaces did not appear at the end of the text when editing.  This I solved using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19569688/1971013): replacing `@" "` with the non-breaking `"\u00a0"`.

The above, however, only shows the space while editing the text field.

How do I also make spaces at the end of the text visible when the text field is **not** being edited?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like triazotan has a solution involving replacing non breaking space for space https://stackoverflow.com/a/20129483/1247248

rednaw has some potentially better version, but someone was complaining of weird side effects
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22512184/1247248

I ended up going with the version of this solution suggested by meaning-matters https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211018/1247248 and that worked for me.

**EDIT**

It looked like a good fix but I found a problem. When you select inside the text and type the cursor jumps to the end of the line. Turns out I should have gone with triazotan's version
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20129483/1247248

Comment: Interesting, I seem to have answered my own question somewhere else :-) Thanks dude!

Comment: not working properly for me, I have to tap spacebar two times to start adding space at the end of string and same happens in case of backspace button to delete last space characters.

Comment: non breakable character \U0A00 should not be used because it yields spcial character while parsing so anybody have another solution ?

Comment: None of these work anymore on iOS 15 and up

Comment: Not working on iOS 16 either. Couldn't find a solution, had to update UI to use left alignment.