# Set the UITextField alignment to the right

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios8.3

I am using an iPhone6+ and iOS 8.3.

When, I want to set the UITextField alignment to the right. But when I send it, the input text jump to left.

```
[tf setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
tf.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:placeholder attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:ISMColor(123, 123, 129)}];
tf.delegate = self;
tf.placeholder = placeholder;
[tf setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
[tf setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight];
```

Comment: Is there any code that interacts with the text field after you define it initially? It would be worth posting that too if so. Have you tried other (simulated) devices than the 6+?

Comment: in my new project ,it work use the same code ,

Comment: I got the same problem, did u found one solution for this ?

Comment: i used a liberary ,it use runtime . drop it from my project,it run will

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // only when adding on the end of textfield && it's a space
    if (range.location == textField.text.length && [string isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        // ignore replacement string and add your own
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:@"\u00a0"];
        return NO;
    }
    // for all other cases, proceed with replacement
    return YES;
}
```

[See more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569688/right-aligned-uitextfield-spacebar-does-not-advance-cursor-in-ios-7/20129483#20129483)