# Rightalignment UITextfield's cursor go left after enter a space

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, text-alignment

1. I setup my UITextfield to be `NSTextAlignmentRight` ,and it's cursor is at the right end as normal.
   [image]
2. When I entered a space the cursor go to the left end of UITextfield.
   [image]
3. I try to fix this problem by implement `UITextFieldDelegate` method

like this:

```
#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  if (range.location == 0 && [string isEqualToString:@" "]) {
    return NO;
  }
return YES;
}
```

But it's a bit of a mess,and I can't input space for the first character.

Is there a better solution to fix this?
Why this bug happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // only when adding on the end of textfield && it's a space
    if (range.location == textField.text.length && [string isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        // ignore replacement string and add your own
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:@"\u00a0"];
        return NO;
    }
    // for all other cases, proceed with replacement
    return YES;
}
```

In case it's not clear, textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: is a UITextFieldDelegate protocol method, so in your example, the above method would be in the viewcontroller designated by [textField setDelegate:self].

If you want your regular spaces back, you will obviously also need to remember to convert the text back by replacing occurrences of @"\u00a0" with @" " when getting the string out of the textfield

**For Ref:** [Right aligned UITextField spacebar does not advance cursor in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569688/right-aligned-uitextfield-spacebar-does-not-advance-cursor-in-ios-7/20129483#20129483)