# Right aligned UITextField spacebar does not advance cursor

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit

I am having issues with white space not being shown in UITextField when the `textAlignment` property is set to `right`. White spaces are only shown when another character is imputed.

Its the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569688/right-aligned-uitextfield-spacebar-does-not-advance-cursor-in-ios-7/20129483#20129483) but the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` solution using non breaking space is not working on ios 15 and and 16.

So far I was unable to fix this on iOS 15 and 16. I have opened issue trough feedback assistant. Anybody had any luck to make this work ?

Comment: Right-alignment on `UITextField` is pretty buggy. Try it without implementing any delegate funcs (such as `shouldChangeCharactersIn`). Start typing. As we know, spaces do not take up space until a non-space char is typed. However... once you have filled the width of the text field -- so it has started scrolling out-of-view to the left -- start typing spaces. Type them slowly, otherwise the quick-double-space will insert a period. See what happens after you've typed 10 to 15 spaces.

Comment: Based on some quick searching and experimenting... I'd say just accept the UIKit behavior if you need right-aligned text. (and file a bug report with Apple)