# Multiple @implementation block in single file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been looking at some sample code from Apple, specifically the `AVCam` project that uses the `AVFoundation` framework.

It the main view controller file, the developer has multiple `@implementation` sections:

```
@implementation AVCamViewController
@implementation AVCamViewController (InternalMethods)
@implementation AVCamViewController (AVCamCaptureManagerDelegate)
```

They also have corresponding `@interface` sections for each.

All of these are in the single `AVCamViewController.m` file.  I've never seen this done before and was wondering about the rationale behind it.

Is this just a personal style?

Does it provide any inherent advantages?

Comment: The below two implementation are called category. Category is simply a way to add instance methods to an existing class without subclassing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called categories.  Here is a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/864877/865967

I'm sure somebody else can provide a more specific reason, but I think when people use this pattern within the same .h/.m files, it's just for readability and separation.